# Google Plus Login without Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I'm developing an app for tablets that may or may not have Google Play Services. I've already setup Google+ login for devices that DO have Google Play Services, but I haven't found a relatively easy way to implement non-Google Play Services Google+ login.

I've implemented OAuth 2.0 login for a wordpress app I did a while back, and I imagine the process will be very similar for this, but I'm mainly looking for solutions that already exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google+ API Client for Java:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/plus/v1

See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2 for authentication information